# What is this type of design called - mobile app

Tags: interface-design, mobile

I'm a new member to this community and I have been looking at quite a few designs recently for an app I intend to work on. I honestly like this kind of style which is used in a lot of modern apps/designs I see online. Unfortunately, I'm not quite aware of what this exact style is called. I've attached an image from [Monobank Enhancements by Denis Perepelenko](https://dribbble.com/shots/4889186-Monobank-Enhancements/attachments/1097570) (Dribbble) as an example.

To clarify further: Its kind of like an off-canvas design where the white/canvas is on top of a more vibrant color/gradient/image. This colorful area contains very little, but important information, while the main 'canvas'/white area contains more info/options. I guess its similar to the Material Design Backdrop, but not exactly the same.

I'd like to search specifically for these designs, but I'm not aware of the exact term.

Thanks for any help :D

[image: Monobank Enhancements by Denis Perepelenko on Dribbble]

Comment: Looks like it's straight out of the iOS 14 mockup resources. Larger rounded corners, iPhone keyboard.

Comment: Is there a specific set of keywords I can search to get more designs like this?

Answer (score 1):

Great question, to be honest!

The industry running... Skeuomorphism -> Flat -> Material design -> ... **What next?**
I'm happy to see more 3d getting back to our life. Seems this become trendy back, but we need more and more concepts in portfolios with the proper keywords to make it visible.

I would call the like:

**Shadow-flat** design ui kit

-Or-

**Deep-flat** material design UI kit

-Or-

Just **Deep-flat** ...

Maybe "Deep Flat" I have seen before somewhere.. I hope more people will jump into this question with more answers on how to call the style becomes next to the Material design... Or we can run a creative session in the comments to fill missed  "..." ?

For the next free-time project, I will definitely come up with something to call it **Deep-flat**!

Comment: I agree with you! There are quite a few designs out there with this style, but no exact term to refer to them... Would really help if there was something concrete to call this style. Deep-flat design sounds quite interesting :D